# postgresql quotes problem

Tags: php, database, postgresql

```
$url = "What's up with "You doing this"";
$q = sprintf ("update user set url='%s'",$url);
pg_query ($db_conn, $q)
```

I want to insert everything into the database exactly as the user wants. I don't want to escape anything. The above would fail for me because of the quotes. I know single quotes have to go around the postgresql string (url='%s'). Since there are double quotes in my url string the query will not update because of it. I'm sure I could do a string replace for all double quotes and make them single quotes but what if the user really wants double quotes. And I cannot use string replace to put a backslash because according to the postgresql docs the slash will be deprecated soon (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/sql-syntax.html) plus that goes against inserting only what the user inputted.

What do people suggest I do?

Answer (score 2):

Use [pg_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php) to escape quote characters in your string.

Answer (score 1):

Use parametrized queries:

```
pg_query_params
        (
        $db_conn,
        "UPDATE user SET url = $1",
        array('What's up with "You doing this"')
        );
```

Comment: I still like the idea of using sprintf though. Is that still possible?

Comment: @keith: yes it is, just change the single quotes into double quotes in your input strings. In your example you don't have any, so you may just leave the string as is. Don't know why don't you want to use parameters, but it's up to you of course.

Comment: You have to escape th single quote in `what's` -> `what\'s`

Comment: @keith: Please don't use sprintf, and use parametrized queries, unless you really want to make your code vulnerable to SQL injection...

Comment: @M42: this is an obsolete syntax and will be removed in the future versions. By `SQL` standard, the single quotes inside the string literals should be represented by the double quotes.

Comment: @Quassnoi: I agree for SQL, but this is a syntax error in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

escape your double quotes in the text like this

> $url = "What\'s up with \"You doing this\"";